# How exactly can we use Yoneda's Lemma?

Tags: category-theory

I have never been truly comfortable with Yoneda's Lemma but have noted the following consequence which seems too good to be true:

$Hom(A,-)\cong Hom(B,-)\Rightarrow A\cong B.$

Is not saying all we need is a nontrivial homomorphism $f:A\to B$ such that the above holds and then f becomes an isomorphism?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, but note that, a priori, there is no morphism $f : A \to B$ inducing the isomorphism $\hom(A,-) \cong \hom(B,-)$ (but the Yoneda lemma tells you that in fact there is). It is also true that if $f : A \to B$ induces an isomorphism $\hom(A,-) \cong \hom(B,-)$, then $f$ is an isomorphism -- again, this is given by the Yoneda lemma. If you want to see applications of the Yoneda lemma, simply search for the word "Yoneda" on this website.

Comment: I didnt quite mean f induces $Hom(A,-)\cong Hom(B,-)$. Rather, if we forget about f and say we only have $Hom(A,-)\cong Hom(B,-)$ for some A, B, then it seems too good to be true to say $A\cong B$ without knowing at least knowing something about how A and B interact. This is why I was asking if we need at least a homomorphism $f:A\to B$ so that Yoneda does the rest and tells us we have an isomorphism.

Comment: No, you don't need a morphism, that's the whole point. It's constructed in the proof. Look for example at $\operatorname{id}_B \in \hom(B,B)$, then it gets sent to some $f : A \to B$ under the isomorphism $\hom(A,-) \cong \hom(B,-)$: that's your morphism.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977267/yoneda-implies-texthomx-z-cong-texthomy-z-rightarrow-x-cong-y/978170#978170